# dropping rows in pandas dataframe based on column entries

Tags: pandas

In a pandas dataframe df

```
name       value

aaaaa        1

aaaa_cntrl   2

bbbb_cntrl   3

ccccc        10
```

I want to drop the rows which have "_cntrl" in the name column. Can you suggest how to do this? I've looked into df.drop but could not figure out how to drop based on string based matches.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use .str.contains:

```
df[~df['name'].str.contains('_cntrl')]
```

Output:

```
    name  value
0  aaaaa      1
3  ccccc     10
```

Comment: is this a typo? Shouldn't it be `df[~df['name'].str.contains('_cntrl')]`?

Comment: @EdChum it wasn't originally, but I changed after reviewing the docs.  '-' also works for 'not' but I guess it isn't the official way.

Comment: OK, I'm just surprised that it behaved the same way